# pattern for json schema validation starting with numbers and ending with K,M and G

Tags: json, regex, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Need a pattern for json schema validator where a string starts with a number and ends with K or M or G,

Say the string should be in format 1267 or 142K or 176M or 185G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Below pattern works fine for the use case mentioned

```
^[0-9]\d*[KGM]  //Number might start with zero's.

^[1-9]\d*[KGM]  //Number will not be having preceding zero's.
```

Comment: Remember, regular expression in JSON Schema is unanchored.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern `^[0-9]\d*[KGM]`  by Ashutosh Sharma also accepts with leading zeros

```
e.g: 0000K is a valid input for ^[1-9]\d*[KGM]$
```

(Regular expression is unanchored in json schema as  Relequestual pointed out, so added $ at end)

The second pattern `^[1-9]\d*[KGM]` suggested doesn't accept `0K` as valid input

---

So to accept 0K as well and not to accept digits with leading zeros(`other than 0`)
`^(0|[1-9]\d*)[KMG]$` should be used


**Details**
`0` boolean or `1-9 followed by any number of digits(0-9)` and then followed by `K or M or G`